# custom initWithStyle: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, initialization

I've subclassed `UITableViewCell` and registered it to my `UITableView` like so:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

But as I've created my own styles for these cells like so:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
MyTableViewCellStyleSent,
MyTableViewCellStyleReceived
} MyTableViewCellStyle;
```

Which is then used like this:

```
-(MyTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

I'd like to have the `initWithStyle:` method use that enum, rather than the "default" `UITableViewCellStyle`.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:):

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

But I cannot figure out how to get `initWithStyle` called, with my new enum.

What's the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't normally create your own styles and if you dequeue a reusable cell this way, it doesn't call `initWithStyle:`.

You should probably add your own "style" property to `MyTableViewCell` with a different name and then set that property once you dequeue the cell.

Another way is to have different cell classes if the design of the cell is different.  They can have a common base class if they share a lot of code.

Comment: I see, yeah they basically share everything aside from a `UIView` position and its background color. Should I create a customer setter method for that style property, and have it change the design whenever I set a different style?

Comment: You need to because cell objects are reused.

Comment: set it up to work like this now, and color changes just fine - but I can't change the position of `UIViews` within the cell. I'm trying to do it by changing the frame property, and I've also tried calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` with no effect